# (Django) Authentication + __init__ argument issue

Tags: python, django, django-views, calendar, arguments

For today I have a question about INIT error which I'm getting while accessing my webpage.

I use @login_required decorator to lock access for not authenticated users to my schedule calendar. While authentication works properly I cannot view my website because of error at the end of this question.

**VIEWS.PY**

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
class CalendarView(generic.ListView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'cal/calendarpage.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        d = get_date(self.request.GET.get('month', None))
        cal = Calendar(d.year, d.month)
        html_cal = cal.formatmonth(withyear=True)
        context['calendar'] = mark_safe(html_cal)
        context['prev_month'] = prev_month(d)
        context['next_month'] = next_month(d)
        return context
```

**URLS.PY**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('calendarpage/', views.CalendarView, name='calendarpage'),
    re_path('event/new/$', views.event, name='event_new'),
        re_path('event/edit/(?P<event_id>\d+)/$', views.event, name='event_edit'),
]
```

If I add .as_view() to my url and remove authentication there is no issue to visit webpage but then there is no authentication which is not desired.

```
TypeError at /calendarpage/

__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/calendarpage/
Django Version:     3.1.2
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Exception Location:     C:\Users\*USER*\Desktop\Python\VENV\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py, line 21, in _wrapped_view
Python Executable:  C:\Users\*USER*\Desktop\Python\VENV\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.8.6
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\*USER*\\Desktop\\Python\\*PROJECT*',
 'C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\*USER*\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0',
 'C:\\Users\\*USER*\\Desktop\\Python\\VENV',
 'C:\\Users\\*USER*\\Desktop\\Python\\VENV\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Tue, 08 Dec 2020 15:08:43 +0100
```

Could You guys please identify the issue which is causing me to get error? As I've seen this is path to global Django decorator but there is no such thing as "init"
The only init I have in my utils file below

**UTILS.PY - WHOLE FILE**

```
class Calendar(HTMLCalendar):
    def __init__(self, year=None, month=None):
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        super(Calendar, self).__init__()

    # formats a day as a td
    # filter events by day
    def formatday(self, day, events):
        events_per_day = events.filter(start_time__day=day)
        d = ''
        for event in events_per_day:
            d += f'<li> {event.get_html_url} </li>'

        if day != 0:
            return f"<td><span class='date'>{day}</span><ul> {d} </ul></td>"
        return '<td></td>'

    # formats a week as a tr
    def formatweek(self, theweek, events):
        week = ''
        for d, weekday in theweek:
            week += self.formatday(d, events)
        return f'<tr> {week} </tr>'

    # formats a month as a table
    # filter events by year and month
    def formatmonth(self, withyear=True):
        events = Event.objects.filter(start_time__year=self.year, start_time__month=self.month)

        cal = f'<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">\n'
        cal += f'{self.formatmonthname(self.year, self.month, withyear=withyear)}\n'
        cal += f'{self.formatweekheader()}\n'
        for week in self.monthdays2calendar(self.year, self.month):
            cal += f'{self.formatweek(week, events)}\n'
        return cal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this question as I found out that I used looped commands XD aythentication was trying to authenticate itself, now corrected >.<